# Riemann Sum to integral form

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Hi please help me in converting this Riemann Sum to integral form:

Any help would be greatly appreciated..!!
[image]

with $\Delta x={c\over an}$

Comment: So, is $\Delta x={1\over n}$?

Comment: \delta x= \frac{c/(an)}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The lim sum  $\lim _{n\to\infty} \Delta x\sum_{k=1}^n f({k\over n})$ can be converted to $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ as long as $f(x)$ is integrable over $(0,1)$ and $\Delta x={1\over n}$, so first find $f(x)$ and then substitute $x={k\over n}$.

**Update**

In the question, it is mentioned that $\Delta x={c\over an}$, hence the integral must be something like $${c\over a}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$

Comment: Hi I am having issue that how do i convert $(1-k/n)log(1-k/n)$ into integral form

Comment: Why not trying $(1-x)\ln (1-x)$?

Comment: I am trying to solve it stepwise by $$\lim_{n\to inf}\Delta x \sum_{k=1}^n(1-\frac{k}{n}) $$ first so I am unable to get it into $$f(a+k\Delta x)=f(x)$$ form for both the terms

Comment: Why should the equality you've written hold? Besides, you don't need to solve it stepwise . The Reimannian sum to integral conversion rule is general, so that you can apply it to any kind of integrable functions.

Comment: $\Delta x=\frac{c}{an}$ whereas $a+k\Delta x= 1-\frac{k}{n}$ therefore equality will hold. Anf I have to find expression for f(x)

Comment: Can you suggest me any resource (book/software) with which I can take help in evaluating the integral?

Comment: I hope https://books.google.com/books?id=X17kBgAAQBAJ helps. Also https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-James-B-Stewart-Pure-Mathematics/s?rh=n%3A13905%2Cp_lbr_one_browse-bin%3AJames+B.+Stewart could be good

Comment: How would I implement this in WolframAlpha ? Im sorry I am very new to this field so asking too much.

Comment: Have no bad feeling. It is OK. First, give your free parameters some known values, or you can just leave them as they are. For example, if you wish to use WolframAlpha for $\int {1\over x^2+\tan^2x}+\ln xdx$ you need to write $$\text{integral 1/(x^2+(tan(x))^2)+log x dx}$$